# How to export LocalNetworkGateway info from multiple Resource Groups

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-group

I'm new to powershell and azure and need to export all the *LocalNetworkGateway* information from multiple *Subscriptions* and *Resource Groups*.

I have a script to export from *Resource Groups* but I have to manually enter the *ResourceGroupName* for each one.

Is there a way to have a variable that contains all the *ResourceGroupNames* so that I don't have to run the script 40 times and manually enter a different *ResourceGroupName* for each?

Any help would be gratefully received.

I have code for one *Resource Group* at a time.

```
Get-AzLocalNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName “RGName” | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Azure\LocalNetworkGateway.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just iterate over resource groups:

```
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup
$resourceGroups.foreach{ 
     Get-AzLocalNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName | 
         Export-Csv -Path "c:\Azure\LocalNetworkGateway.csv" -Append
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance with powershell what does the 'filter_if_you_need_it' mean? And if I don't want to enter the separate names in the "RGName" field what happens with that? How does that get automatically populated with every ResourceGroupName?

Comment: you can skip that part (where-object). its just to showcase you can filter resource groups if you need to

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not returning any result. However, running Get-AzLocalNetworkGateway on it's own and then manually entering a ResourceGroupName manually when prompted, does provide output.

Comment: Now all I need to find out is how to apply that across multiple subscriptions within the one Azure environment....any thoughts on that?

Comment: yeah, if you got enough permissions you can just create another loop with subscription. if you cant figure out how you can create a new question, I'll gladly help you ;) ps. if this helped you - consider accepting this answer as a valid one ;)

Comment: Thank you...I'll create a new question as you suggest. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I've created a new question as you suggested.